# Asp.Net Core Identity SendGrid mails are not being sent

Tags: c#, sendgrid, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to find out why the account verification email is not being sent from my app when creating a new user account.

I was able to send two emails on one of my first attempts. The emails ended up in my spam filter, but they did get through. I do not know what may have changed since then.

Checking the SendGrid control panel, I can confirm that two emails was sent the first day I tried it, but none of my later attempts have generated any emails.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#debug-email) suggests to set a breakpoint on `EmailSender.Execute`. I have done that, and found that it is indeed not being hit. How do I debug further?

The SendGrid account information is specified in secrets.json:

```
{
  "SendGridUser": "{account name}",
  "SendGridKey": "{api-key}"
}
```

A service is configured in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
```

AuthMessageSenderOptions:

```
public class AuthMessageSenderOptions
{
    public string SendGridUser { get; set; }
    public string SendGridKey { get; set; }
}
```

The EmailSender service:

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; } //set only via Secret Manager

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
    }

    public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
    {
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress("my@email.com", Options.SendGridUser),
            Subject = subject,
            PlainTextContent = message,
            HtmlContent = message
        };
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

        // Disable click tracking.
        // See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html
        msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);

        return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

A user is created like this:

```
// user is an ApplicationUser-object
IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(auto.Map<ApplicationUser>(user), "P&55w0rd");
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    ApplicationUser u = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName);
    if (u != null)
    { 
        // newUser.RN is the role name to be assigned to the new user
        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(u, newUser.RN);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = user.Id });
}
else
{
    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
    }
}
```

A new user is created, added to the role and we are redirected to Users/Details/{id}, but the account verification email is not sent.

Comment: The code that you have included has nothing to do with sending email. Please check [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidelines: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*

Comment: @HoomanBahreini I know that. The code I included shows how the user is created. The sending of emails is handeled by Identity, of which I do not have the code.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini I have added more relevant information in the question. I think you can remove your vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be surprised if Identity does it by default, only by setting up the EmailSender. You do not seem to provide any logic for the confirmation and nowhere to call the EmailSender.

You need to inject the `IEmailSender` as a service in your controller where you are creating the user, and add the logic to generate a confirmation token and actually send the email.

I'd expect something in the lines of:

```cs
var token = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
var confirmationLink = Url.Action(nameof(ConfirmEmail), "Account", 
   new { token , email = user.Email }, 
   Request.Scheme);
await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, "Confirmation email link", confirmationLink);
```

Of course you could further look how to make your email prettier, but that's the core of it.

Also, just to make sure that you have the whole picture, Identity does not also provide an email implementation by default, you also have to set it up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#install-sendgrid

Comment: That seems a bit like manual labour to me. I was under the impression that userManager does the sending of emails for you when creating a user and when a user requests a new password. That is how I understand things after reading the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I have added the EmailSender service in the question. I didn't think it would be necessary, as it is shown in the documentation I have linked to in the question, but it clarifies how the emails would be sent.

Comment: I'll have to insist. I browsed the code for userManager.CreateAsync and there is no code path that will automatically send any email. This requires too many assumptions to be done by default. Sending an email is being made in the template during the Register action: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#examine-register , where it uses the `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync`

Comment: But how did I manage to have two emails sent the first time I tried? As I say in the question, I don't know what has changed since I got it to work.

Comment: Heh... It seems that the emails that worked before (and still work) were the ones where a user clicks the link to have a confirmation email sent to them from `/Identity/Account/Manage/Email`, and not where a user is created in `Users/Create`.

Answer (score 1):

Sendgrid does not send the emails if the sender's email is not authenticated properly.
Hope this will be helpful for someone.
Doc: https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/sender_auth